# How To Take Value Size Of Schema Postgres Using ActiveRecord Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, schema, multi-tenant

I have multi-tenant application using Rails 3 + Postgresql
i want get size of schema..

on sizes_cotroller.rb

```
class SizesController < ApplicationController

     def index

      @tablesize = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(%q{select pg_size_pretty(CAST((SELECT SUM(pg_total_relation_size(table_schema || '.' || table_name) ) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'schema2') As bigint) )  As schema_size})
     end


end
```

but the output showing this :

[["264 kB"]]

how to take just the value of size?

**example**

264

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the format is always `[["### kB"]]`, one way (in Ruby) is to do a bit of string manipulation

```
[1] pry(main)> [["264 kB"]].to_s.gsub(/\D/, '').to_i
=> 264
```